# How to create an alert with Stackdriver which checks GKE pods/deployments statuses?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

Also I would like the alert to be triggered if GKE cluster ceases to be reachable, hence no status for the pods/deployments.

The question is about the new Stackdriver for Kubernetes which is currently in beta.

Actually, I wonder what is supposed to happen on a pod alert if the cluster is manually destroyed. Does Stackdriver detects that the cluster is gone and still manages the alert (maybe with '0' value depending on the metric)?

Comment: Had you looked into `container/uptime` metric ? It seems to be the closest available to what you need https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_kubernetes

Comment: @c69 The problem is that it can be normal that a container stops running, when scaling down. So I don't think it's a solution to use container/uptime. Do you agree?

Comment: i see.. Well, maybe something creative like dynamically create/delete alerting policies via API upon cluster creation/destruction https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.alertPolicies/create

Comment: @c69 yes I think that's a possible approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may find this useful, [this](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/observing) is the guide for Stackdriver kubernetes engine monitoring, there you may check the alerting and how to observe your system.

Also, [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/migration#resource_type_changes) it is a list of the metrics for the new Stackdriver kubernetes engine vs the previous metrics in case you were familiar.

And [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/resources#tag_k8s_container) are the full list of metrics, always useful.

Comment: thanks, that's useful but it does not answer the question

Comment: The alerts are created as normal you just need to use the correct metrics and parameters.